# Getting the balance in a particular month with the payments in the following month by Account Month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a account table that has the accountno, performance month and balance. I also have a payments table where I have the account number ,payment date and the payment amount. Now I want to create a result table having the performance month ,total distinct accounts from account table for that month, total balance for that performance month from account table and the total payments for the same set of accounts and the next month (performance month +1) (extracting next month from payment date) from the payments table.

Account table:

| Accountno | PerformanceMonth | Balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Jan-23 | 1456 |
| 2134 | Jan-23 | 234 |
| 3412 | Jan-23 | 904 |
| 1234 | Feb-23 | 781 |
| 2134 | Feb-23 | 3415 |
| 6751 | Feb-23 | 567 |
| 6751 | Mar-23 | 5600 |
| 4512 | Mar-23 | 770 |
| 2134 | Mar-23 | 546 |

Payments table:

| Account No | Payment date | Paymentamount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2134 | 1/3/2023 | 56 |
| 2134 | 1/3/2023 | 134 |
| 2134 | 2/3/2023 | 125 |
| 2134 | 2/3/2023 | 90 |
| 5165 | 2/3/2023 | 1200 |
| 2134 | 3/15/2023 | 2000 |
| 2134 | 3/23/2023 | 500 |
| 2134 | 4/5/2023 | 350 |
| 3412 | 1/3/2023 | 200 |
| 3412 | 2/20/2023 | 800 |
| 3412 | 2/27/2023 | 40 |
| 1234 | 2/10/2023 | 400 |
| 1234 | 2/15/2023 | 300 |
| 1234 | 2/21/2023 | 150 |
| 1234 | 3/5/2023 | 300 |
| 1234 | 3/7/2023 | 100 |
| 1234 | 3/21/2023 | 20 |
| 6751 | 3/11/2023 | 300 |
| 6751 | 3/12/2023 | 120 |
| 6751 | 4/5/2023 | 1500 |
| 6751 | 4/12/2023 | 380 |
| 6751 | 4/22/2023 | 1200 |

Result table:

| PerformanceMonth | Total accounts | Total balance | Total payment next month |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-23 | 3 | 2594 | 1905 |
| Feb-23 | 3 | 4763 | 3340 |
| Mar-23 | 3 | 6916 | 3430 |

```
create table #account as
(accountno int,
performancemonth date,
balance float)

insert into #account values
('1234','1/1/2023','1456'),
('2134','1/1/2023','234'),
('3412','1/1/2023','904'),
('1234','2/1/2023','781'),
('2134','2/1/2023','3415'),
('6751','2/1/2023','567'),
('6751','3/1/2023','5600'),
('4512','3/1/2023','770'),
('2134','3/1/2023','546')

create table #payments as
(accountno int,
paymentdate date,
paymentamount float)

insert into #payments values
('2134','1/3/2023','56'),
('2134','1/3/2023','134'),
('2134','2/3/2023','125'),
('2134','2/3/2023','90'),
('5165','2/3/2023','1200'),
('2134','3/15/2023','2000'),
('2134','3/23/2023','500'),
('2134','4/5/2023','350'),
('3412','1/3/2023','200'),
('3412','2/20/2023','800'),
('3412','2/27/2023','40'),
('1234','2/10/2023','400'),
('1234','2/15/2023','300'),
('1234','2/21/2023','150'),
('1234','3/5/2023','300'),
('1234','3/7/2023','100'),
('1234','3/21/2023','20'),
('6751','3/11/2023','300'),
('6751','3/12/2023','120'),
('6751','4/5/2023','1500'),
('6751','4/12/2023','380'),
('6751','4/22/2023','1200')

create table #result as
(performancemonth date,
totalaccounts int,
totalbalance float,
totalpaymentnextmonth float)

insert into #result values
('1/1/2023','3','2594','1905),
('2/1/2023','3','4763','3340),
('3/1/2023','3','6916','3430)
```

Query tried:

```
SELECT  performance_month,
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.account_number) AS total_accounts,
    SUM(a.balance) AS total_balance, 
    COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(p.payment_date) = MONTH(DATE_ADD(a.performance_month, INTERVAL 1 MONTH)) THEN p.amount ELSE 0 END), 0) AS total_next_month_payments 
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN payment p 
    ON a.account_number = p.account_number 
GROUP BY performance_month;
```

Thanks

Comment: Aside... `float` and `real` are [approximate numerics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql) and should not be used for financial calculations. Unless of course you're happy with those calculations being approximately wrong all of the time and leaking money one way or the other.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: Sure!..I will take your feedback

Comment: Also, don't use ambiguous date; there arent 22 months in the year. Use unambiguous formats like `yyyyMMdd`, especially when you're posting on a website where plenty of people outside of America are likely to be helping you.

Comment: Are you really using `SQL Server` ? `SQL Server` does not support syntax `create table #account as`

Comment: It also doesn't support syntax such as `INTERVAL 1 MONTH`. Are you perhaps using MySQL? That doesn't like dates `MM/DD/YYYY`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You
can use outer apply(join with payments) for calcaute Totalpaymentnextmonth

and use Convert(char(3), a.performancemonth, 0) to Get shortName month

The calculations you made for the month "Jan-2023" are wrong (your  calculations =1905 but correct is 3105)

```
SELECT  
   Convert(char(3), a.performancemonth, 0)+'-'+ 
   cast( DATEPART(YEAR, a.performancemonth) as  varchar(100)) ,
    
    COUNT(DISTINCT a.accountno) AS total_accounts,
    SUM(DISTINCT a.balance) AS total_balance 
    ,sum(distinct sumpaymentamount) as Totalpaymentnextmonth

FROM #account a
LEFT JOIN #payments p 
    ON a.accountno = p.accountno 
outer apply (

                select 
                sum(aa.paymentamount) as sumpaymentamount  
                from #payments aa
                where 
                        DATEPART( YEAR,aa.paymentdate)= 
                        DATEPART( YEAR, dateadd(MONTH,1,a.performancemonth))
                    
                    and DATEPART( MONTH,aa.paymentdate)= 
                        DATEPART( MONTH, dateadd(MONTH,1,a.performancemonth))

)f
GROUP BY 
          Convert(char(3), a.performancemonth, 0)+'-'+ 
          cast( DATEPART(YEAR, a.performancemonth) as  varchar(100))
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/KllU8GfR)